# Does comma separators in type definition in C guarantee the order?

Tags: c, c99, c11

Comma **operators** have the lowest precedence and left-to-right associativity, so this guarantees the order like:

```
i = ++j, j = i++;
```

`i` will be 2, and then `j` will be 1 after this statement if `i` and `j` are both 0 at first.

However, does comma **separators** in type definition in C also guarantee the order? Such as

```
int i = 1, j = ++i;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your example with the comma operator, `i = ++j, j = i++;`,  is well-defined because the comma operator is a sequence point.

Precedence/associativity is not enough to guarantee this -- they are different to order-of-evaluation and sequence points. For example, `i * 2 + i++ * 3` is undefined because there are no sequence points.

---

The comma separator *between declarators*, e.g. `int i = 1, j = i++;`, is also a sequence point. This is covered by C11 6.7.6/3, C99 6.7.5/3:

> A *full declarator* is a declarator that is not part of another declarator. The end of a full declarator is a sequence point.

So there is a sequence point after `i = 1`, and this code is well-defined.

---

However, the comma separator between function arguments `f(i, i++)` is not a sequence point; so that code causes undefined behaviour.

---

*Note:* In C11, the term *sequence point* was mostly replaced with more complicated sequencing relations in order to clearly specify a threading model, but that does not affect the above discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure whether C89 guaranteed the declarator order

Comment: You say, *The comma separator is different to the comma operator.* But in the rest of the answer there is no more mention of the comma operator. Is that an oversight?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, the question was "However, does comma **separators** in type definition in C also guarantee the order?" . My opening sentence just clarifies that I'm not talking about the comma operator (especially for other readers who didn't realize there was a difference)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my first sentence was a bit unclear as you say, so I've refactored my post. I also realized that OP's rationale about the comma operator wasn't right, so have addressed that too.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, and here's the reason. Think about what the comma is saying. All it is saying is "hey, I have a thing I want to do on the left hand side of this comma, once you do that thing go to the thing on the right and do that as well. You can also think of it as a shorter way of doing this

```
int i = 1;
int j = i++;
```

i has already been allocated somewhere in memory so all that happens with j is it takes that value stored in i, increments it, and sets it equal to j.

So in the case of

```
int i = 1, j = ++i;
```

All you are saying is create an integer, set it equal to one, now move on to the next command, which will be an int called j, and set it equal to whatever i is when it is incremented.

So to fully answer your question, yes, it guarantee's the order because the compiler will execute everything top down, left to right unless it is told otherwise.

Comment: This incorrectly suggests that `f(i, i++)` has well-defined behavior.

Comment: That's not what he asked. He asked does the comma guarantee the order in the example int i = 1, j = ++i; He didn't ask about function arguments.

Comment: The point is that this hand-waving argument leads to erroneous conclusions, so cannot be correct.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what I'm saying. If you read his question there is nothing about that f(i, i++). That got brought up in someones answer, it is not what he asked. He asked in the case of i = 1, j = i++ does the comma guarantee the order, and in that case it does.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming C works the same as C# in this respect, the comma-separated values (int i = 0, j = 0;) should stay in order.

The difference in i++ vs ++i is validation time:

```
int i = 0;

bool iGTZ = i++ > 0;//false

i = 0; iGTZ = ++i > 0;//true
```

A little more than what you asked but the declaration order is guaranteed. And if you or someone reading this didn't know that hopefully it helps. :)

Comment: The question is whether there is left-to-right evaluation around the comma separator; not what `++` does

Comment: @MattMcNabb If you read my answer I addressed that question and added additional information ranging to other areas of the supplied code within the area of timing.

Comment: You just said "assuming C works the same as C#" without any justification for making that assumption. C doesn't work the same as C# in other areas (e.g. `f(i, i++)`)

Comment: I said very specifically "In this respect" I have developed in C, C++, C# and VB.Net, I'm aware of the differences, I merely left the possibility that I was wrong. Humility doesn't imply lack of knowledge.

Comment: This question asks for knowledge rather than humility. The asker is looking for a definitive answer with facts rather than assumptions.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Really?? What are the differences?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree, maybe my approach to this answer was flawed, there's not much use to edit my answer now but I will keep this in mind in the future, thank you.  And rpax in Matt's defense there are definitely distinctive differences between the two languages, one being the use of the CLR or lack there of, it's a very interesting topic to research if you get the chance.

Comment: Irrespective of the CLR, sequencing is handled quite differently between C++ and C#.

Comment: That's why I said "one" being. A full discussion of the difference between C, C++ and C# is probably beyond the scope of this comment section.